# Opera high memory usage

Tags: memory, opera

The newest versions of Opera are using a lot of memory (certainly when you've got multiple tabs opened) (I'm currently using Opera 24) 
With only 2GB ram on my pc, it is impossible to open multiple programs whilst browsing on various tabs with Opera - does anyone have a solution to reduce the ram usage?

I've found a few websites mentioning changing the memory cache settings in Preferences > Advanced > History - yet in the newest versions of Opera, I haven't found this option...

Comment: Opera now depends on Chrome which uses a lot of RAM to isolate the tabs by running multiple processes. Switch to Firefox if you have not enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

From the Opera menu, enabled Developer tools. Then go to the Opera menu: Developer Tools: Task Manager. This will allow you to see what tabs/plug-ins/extensions are using memory.

If you are feeling experimental, you can type in the below in the address field and read the information about this experimental feature that significantly reduces memory.

```
opera://flags/#tab-hibernation
```

Comment: don't know if this was just me or is it a bug, but enabling tab hibernation on portable opera v33, 32bits version, wiped the entire \Data contents where the user profile was stored